# How to add Alamofire in Swift Project

Tags: swift, alamofire

i am trying to add Alamofire in my application. but each time xcode gives error "Alamofire framework not found".

i am using xcode 7.3 version.

i tried each solutions like

- Open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj
- Add Pod again. yes i also clean pod and update

than after i download Alamofire Libraries. it also giving error.
        "No such module alamofire"
my podfile looks like

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.3'
```

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

Please help me to find out solution

Comment: Did you forget `import Alamofire` line in head of your swift source file?

Comment: yes i import. no such module alamofire

Comment: And you have use_frameworks! line in Podfile and properly set target?

Comment: Why don't you use it with Carthage? It's much more simpler! 

Comment: i done it by using Manually instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project folder and add a pod file. You can also do this by opening terminal and in your project root run:

```
pod init
```

Close the terminal and project.

For add workspace in project open terminal again

```
pod install
```

Comment: #import alamofire

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases, a developer uses third-party classes either installing pods or add it directly to the project but sometimes it happens those third-party libraries are not directly accessible. Though I would recommend going with following steps that could be helpful.

1. Download Alamofire library file and add its required library file in one folder of your project.
2. Now, Goto your project > Select Targets > Build Settings
3. Search for "Framework Search Paths" and click on "+"
4. Write there like "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Project-Name/ThirdPartyClasses/Alamofire" with "non-recursive"

The 4th step contains the path where you have put your alamofire library file. I have mentioned path of my project.